# How to access SQL messages from R?

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

Is there a way to get print message outputs to R from an SQL call?

for example

```
ret >- RODBC::sqlQuery(dbh, "print('me'))
```

returns character(0), but if you run it in SQL it will be a message

Thanks

Comment: I'm not *that* familiar with `RODBC` (I'm more familiar with `DBI` and `odbc`), but I suspect not: the packages tend to deal with "resultsets", which are returned *data* packets. Printing something on the console feels like more of a SQL-console thing. I could easily be missing something ...

Comment: These are called info messages, they are not resultsets and there is no reason to expect they should be returned as such. Perhaps there is some function on the connection that will return them?

Comment: SQL Server's `print` messages are similar to `raiserror()` messages with severity 0. Looking through the source code at [https://github.com/cran/RODBC/blob/master/src/RODBC.c](https://github.com/cran/RODBC/blob/master/src/RODBC.c) it seems that RODBC does track error messages in a linked list that can be accessed via `RODBCGetErrMsg` which gets exposed as `RODBC::odbcGetErrMsg(channel)`. Try `RODBC::odbcGetErrMsg(dbh)` to see if you can see your `print` output there.